# Adding tool tip functionality to a wpf control that does not descend from FrameworkElement

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I'm working on a custom class that descends from DataGridColumn.  The base class for DataGridColumn is DependencyObject.  As such, it does not have a Tooltip property.

I want my custom class to have a Tooltip property.  Actually, I want it to also have a ToolTipTemplate property that is a DataTemplate that can be used to generate the ToolTip.  How do I go about adding this functionality to my class?

Tony

Answer (score 1):

Its a common misconception that `DataGridColumn` being a dependency object, is part of the visual tree. It is not. So even if we create an **inheritable** dependency property (just like `DataContext` or `FlowDirection` which automatically propagates down the visual parent to its child elements), the new property of `ToolTip` wont descend down to individual cells, as those cells are not the children of the data grid column.

So now that we know this, the only way left is to add a binding in the `CellStyle` and bind to the self `Column.ToolTip` property. Just because you have decided to go with `ToolTipTemplate`, then you could add a `ContentControl` and then bind to its content template.

Something like this...

```
   <tk:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" RowHeaderWidth="15"
                ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyData}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <tk:DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContentControl 
                             ContentTemplate="{Binding Column.ToolTipTemplate,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                     AncestorType={x:Type tk:DataGridCell}}}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                             Binding="{Binding Column.ToolTipTemplate,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </tk:DataGrid.CellStyle>
        ....
    </tk:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Since it's the DataGridCell that's in the visual tree and not the DataGridColumn, and since the GenerateElement method is passed a reference to the cell object, could I just stick my ToolTipTemplate into the  cell's ToolTipTemplate (assuming it has the property) in the code behind?

Comment: I tried this but my template is not being used to generate the tool tip.  My class descends from DataGridColumn, not DataGridCell.  Should I change DataGridCell to DataGridColumn (or my custom class) in the RelativeSource clause of the ContentControl?